# Android: how to make multiline text auto scroll down?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make the multiline text auto scroll down as I add in more text:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TypeBox"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ReceiverName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.65"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions" >
</EditText>
```

I have tried searching for it but all i could find is auto scroll of a text box within a scroll view.

Comment: What do you mean? Please rephrase what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what i actually want to do is that i need the text box to automatically scroll down to show the latest input as i add more line than what the text box can contain,
currently whenever the text is more line than what the text box can contain and when i try to add more it always show the top and i have to scroll down to see whatever i have inputted

Answer (score 1):

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:editable="true"
android:enabled="true"
android:minLines="6"
android:maxLines="6"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Refer this link for more info

https://alvinalexander.com/source-code/android/android-edittext-isscrollcontainer-example-how-make-multiline-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to add a line:

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: what does textfilter do??
i have tried it but it didn't have any effect

Answer (score 0):

> Add bellow code in activity onCreate(), this Add scroll behavior to
>   text view

```
    textView.setMovementMbehavior ScrollingMovementMethod());

 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="text"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
```